# Append text for printing before and after a JTable

Tags: java, swing, printing, jtable, graphics2d

I am trying to print a `JTable` and the `print()` method works great till I come to this scenario. Lets say I want to print before, in the first page only (not header) the text "Report" and on the end the text "This is the end of report". I would like once more to clarify that I don't need a header or footer only this text to appear in the top of the first and bottom of the last page when I print them.

How can I do this?

Comment: Not possible. Actuall dublicate!

Comment: ok. I think it is deleted! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is to `append()` a series of suitable `Printable` instances to a [`java.awt.print.Book`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/print/Book.html), as shown [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0261__2D-Graphics/PrintBook.htm).

Addendum: `JTable` has a [`getPrintable()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getPrintable%28javax.swing.JTable.PrintMode,%20java.text.MessageFormat,%20java.text.MessageFormat%29) method that should simplify things; here's an outline and simple title `Printable`:

```
PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
Book book = new Book();
book.append(new Title(), pj.defaultPage());
book.append(table.getPrintable(...), pj.defaultPage());
book.append(new EndPage(), pj.defaultPage());
pj.setPageable(book);
pj.print();
...
private static class Title implements Printable {

    Font font = new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 48);

    @Override
    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int pageIndex)
        throws PrinterException {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());
        g2d.setFont(font);
        g2d.setColor(Color.black);
        g2d.drawString("Report", 50, 200);
        return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but still seems to advanced for my skills!!! Seems to complicate for printing only 2 lines. Is this the way it has to be? Something more simple?

Comment: I've elaborated above; you may have to experiment a little using your platform's print preview.