# Print into file

Tags: java, ubuntu, printing, jtable

After my previous question that was ansered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10250772/append-text-for-printing-before-and-after-a-jtable/10251531#comment13178413_10251531) , I can manage to print the pages I need but with a small problem. With Jtable.print there is always appear a window with the preferences for printing , select printer even print in a file the resaults.
With the   pj.print() I got an outcome to my printer when ever is connected and no other promt before . I tried   pj.printDialog(); and gives me the prompt window with printers etc but nor the normal printer or the the print to file gives a resault. 
What am I doing wrong? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The printing dialogs vary across platforms and OS versions, so I'm probably seeing something different. In addition to `printDialog()`, you might try [`pageDialog()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/dialog.html), which has a promising looking <kbd>`Printer…`</kbd> button.

Comment: pg.pageDialog(); I get error, probably there has to be something in the parenthesis...

Comment: Tried  pj.pageDialog(pj.defaultPage()); and now a window appear in order to select page orrientation etc, but there is no print button to print.

Comment: On my system, I can select a printer or see a PDF preview. I think Windows has an XPS printer. You might edit your question to indicate your OS & version. Maybe somebody with that combination can test your [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: If you update your question with this and add the Ubuntu tag, more people will see the new information.

Comment: I edited with the tag of Ubuntu. Is that what you mean update?Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome; sorry it's not more helpful. Editing your question with new information moves it to the top of the active list, as discussed [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046/163188). It shows progress, while leaving the question open. Adding a [short example](http://sscce.org/) is often very appealing to new viewers.