# Book class: How to print continually with no page separation

Tags: java, swing, printing, jtable, graphics2d

After [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10250772/append-text-for-printing-before-and-after-a-jtable) answer about how to print some predefined text before and after a `JTable` (not header and footer), I want to go further.
With the `Book` class, it is possible like the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10250772/append-text-for-printing-before-and-after-a-jtable) to print different formated pages in sequence; but here arises the problem: What if I need to make it one after an other text? So when the first text finish the `JTable` uses the rest of the free page and goes on with the subsequent text.

In this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10250772/append-text-for-printing-before-and-after-a-jtable) an entire page is wasted just for the word "REPORT". Is there a way to do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `java.awt.print.Book` is page oriented, but you can `print()` any component anywhere on the page, as shown in [*Printing the Contents of a User Interface*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/gui.html). You can `translate()` the graphics context to compose the page.

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());
table.getTableHeader().print(g2d);
g2d.translate(0, table.getTableHeader().getHeight());
table.print(g2d);
```

Comment: Thank you trashgod, I will try your code soon and hopfully once again you will get a correct answer!

Comment: I am sorry but my experience doesnt help me to mix the code in the example with this on the previous example. Could you please help me?

Comment: This code would go in your implementation of the `Printable` interface.