# I need to print a JTextArea and a JTable on the same page.

Tags: java, swing, printing, jtable, jtextarea

I am trying to print a jtable and jtextarea on the same page. I have tried this so far

```
private void printButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
// TODO add your handling code here:


JTextArea detailArea = new JTextTable();        
JTable detailTable = new JTable();


    int page = 1;
    MessageFormat mf = new MessageFormat(detailArea.getText()));
    MessageFormat mf2 = new MessageFormat(Integer.toString(page));
page++;

try

    {
        detailTable.print(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH,mf,mf2);
    }

    catch(PrinterException p)

    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Printer Exception");
    }    

}
```

This is a bad solution as it prints the text of the textarea as a bold header. I need a method to print the Jtable with text above it on the same page.

Any help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The article [*How to Print Tables*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/printtable.html) may give you some ideas on how to construct your [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

- Use `getPrintable()` to obtain a `Printable` from both the `JTextArea` and `JTable`; render each sequentially in your own implementation of `Printable`.
- Override `getPrintable()` to decorate your table using the `JTextArea` content, as shown in `TablePrintDemo3`.

A `java.awt.print.Book`, outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10251531/230513), may be a useful way to organize your document.