# How to print a jtable with a image in the header?

Tags: java, image, swing, printing, jtable

i want to print something like this

IMAGE

TITLE

JTABLE

i know to print a jtable with the title in a messageFormat header but i dont know how to add the image

The image is a logo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try the approach shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10251531/230513). Use `drawImage()` instead of `drawString()` in your `Image` printable.

```
private static class Image implements Printable {…}
private static class Title implements Printable {…}

PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
Book book = new Book();
book.append(new Image(), pj.defaultPage());
book.append(new Title(), pj.defaultPage());
book.append(table.getPrintable(...), pj.defaultPage());
book.append(new EndPage(), pj.defaultPage());
pj.setPageable(book);
pj.print();
```