# Printing from a JTable including logo and footer

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable that a user can input data. I have an image that I would want to put at the top of my page when printed and also another image that I would want to work as footer. How do I print these on the same page including data from for  a jtable(my images to works as logo and footer are not part of the table; i would take them from my directories)...I mean make it as shown in the image below. I would appreciate any links and ideas.

[image]

Comment: this simple idea isn't implemented in Printing API, you have to bothering with custom painting (area for JTables view must be calculated programatically and reduced to available Rectangle/Area), I'm sure that here must be something about

Comment: [crossposted](https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/491187/printing-jtable-with-header-image-and-footer-image)

Comment: @trashgod you have marked this question duplicate but it's not. When I use the ....book.append() as shown here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24126920/how-to-print-a-jtable-with-a-image-in-the-header) it is printing on two pages but I want it on ONE page.