# Integrating Classes -JTable, Graphics, Printable

Tags: java, swing, printing, jtable, graphic

I have a JTable that I would want to capture user input which later would printed. When printing, I have an image that I would want to be a Header and the other a footer. I have tried this example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24126920/how-to-print-a-jtable-with-a-image-in-the-header) but it is printing the things on two separate sheets. I want it to print on ONE SHEET OF PAPER not two.Here is the code that I have been using -here only this part is necessary:

```
    print.addActionListener((ActionEvent evt) -> {
        if (evt.getSource().equals(print)) {
            PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
            Book bk = new Book();
            bk.append(new HeaderImage(), pj.defaultPage());
            bk.append(table.getPrintable(JTable.PrintMode.NORMAL, null, null), pj.defaultPage());
            pj.setPageable(bk);
            try {
                pj.print();
            } catch (PrinterException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MainWindow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }

    });
```

The `HeaderImage` class `implements Printable`. The problem is that the Header Image is being printed on the first page and the table on the second page-I want them on one page!

I found a good implementation of what I want [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/printtable.html); but now the challenge is I am not able to integrate these things. Let me set it the way I would want it done. Suppose we have a main class as follows:

```
  mainClass{
      JTable table = new JTable();
  }
```

Now I have my `PrintTableClass` that `implements Printable` as follows:

```
public class PrintTable implements Printable {

    protected int x, y, width;
    protected int orientation;
    protected BufferedImage image;
    {
    try{
        image=ImageIO.read(MainClass.class.getResourceAsStream("images/header.PNG"));}
        catch(IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {

        x = (int) pageFormat.getImageableX();
        y = (int) pageFormat.getImageableY();
        int ih = image.getHeight();
        int iw = image.getWidth();
        graphics.drawImage(image, x, y, width, ih, null);
        return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
    }
}
```

Now my Question is: Isn't there a way to use my `table` in `PrintTable`     class the way we have done it with the `image` so that when I will be printing I would write only this code -`book.append(new PrintTable(),printerJob.getDefaultPage)`-with this the table and the  header will be printed on one page.

I appreciate any ideas regarding integrating these things.

Is there something like or a way to make it work this way?

```
public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {

    graphics.drawTable(table, x, y, width, ih, null);//check this line.

    return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
}
```

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10250772/230513), for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10251531/230513).

Comment: @trashgod you would do good to look at the last part of my question.

Comment: @trashgod Please these things are different, the solutions there are not doing what I want-with those solutions, the image is being printed on first page and the table on the second. This is not what I want. I want both the table and the image on one page. Please if you mind to look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26678235/java-change-margins-when-printing-jtable) I could have posted the classes but there are a lot big -one of the people here named it **code dump**

Comment: Have you tried the approach in `TablePrintDemo3`?

Comment: @trashgod I have tried that but only the table is being printed. let me post a new question with the classes pruned.